# Doubt about why to consider partial pressures in calculating vapour pressure

Tags: pressure, kinetic-theory, evaporation

I am confused as to why the partial pressure is considered while calculating whether a liquid will evaporate in atmosphere or not.
But doesn't the reasoning given of molecules colliding also consider effect of random collisions or is it just molecules' going in and going out?

Does Dalton's law not consider the effect of collisions and pressure by foreign particles? Because by molecular picture, it makes some sense to me that pressure of any overbearing fluid will affect vaporization, as we see by example that substances liquefy when kept in pressurized atmospheres.

So why do we consider only partial pressure? My guess is that at low enough pressures, such collision and interactions are negligible and Dalton's law is valid for vaporization considerations only for low pressures. Please clarify.

Comment: Partial pressure is a property of the liquid. You decide whether a liquid boils or not by comparing the outside pressure with the partial pressure. You are essentially comparing whether the liquid has enough strength to overcome the atmospheric pressure or whether the atmospheric pressure will push it back. But of course, there will always be few molecules that will keep escaping and the liquid will evaporate slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vapor pressure of a pure substance is only a function of temperature, and it is not a function of the presence of an air atmosphere.  When the vapor pressure of a pure substance is higher than the partial pressure of that same substance on top of the liquid surface, the liquid will evaporate.  When the partial pressure of the substance on top of the liquid surface is greater than the vapor pressure of that substance, condensation will occur.  Note that this is a dynamic process, where molecules are continuously leaving the liquid and returning to the liquid, usually at different rates.  For more info on vapor pressure, see the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_equation

Comment: seems more like an experimental fact I need to come in terms with and we theorized the molecular picture based on that. thanks!

Comment: @SauravKumar, I suspect that the amount of an atmosphere such as air over the liquid surface impacts the rate at which molecules evaporate and condense on the liquid surface (e.g., they "get in the way"), but it affects the rate of BOTH evaporation and condensation.  However, that atmosphere does NOT affect the outcome of whether a liquid will show net evaporation or net condensation at the liquid surface.  Note that this is a conjecture on my part, and others in this group may have information on the rate of evaporation/condensation vs. atmospheric pressure.